# Firebase-database - How to fetch child values from multiple children nodes and store in Swift Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure is as follows:

```
"routines": {
  "users unique identifier": {
    "routine unique identifier": {
      "routine_name": "routine name",
      "routine_create_date": "routine created date",
      "exercises": {
        "exercise name": {
          "Sets": "number of sets"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When retrieving data I am wanting to store each `routine` as an object to load in to a `UITableView`. The routine structure I am using is:

```
struct Routine {
  var routineName: String!
  var routineExercisesAndSets: [String:Int]!
}
```

How can I retrieve the values from this so that for each `Routine` model I can have  `Routine(routineName: "Legs", routineExercisesAndSets: ["Squats":4,"Lunges":4,"Calf Raises":4])` where the dictionary of exercises is the `exercise name`:`number of sets`.

I am currently using a different structure and can nearly get the result I want through:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("routines").child(userId)
var routineTemp = Routine()
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in  
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
        routineTemp.routineName = dictionary["routineName"] as! String
        let enumerator = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "exercises").children
        var exercisesAndSets = [String:Int]()
        while let item = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
            exercisesAndSets[item.key] = item.value! as? Int
        }
        routineTemp.routineExercisesAndSets = exercisesAndSets
        print(routineTemp)           
    }    
} , withCancel: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the values for each exercise and their respective `numberOfSets` using the following code:

```
guard let userId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
    return
}

let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("routines").child(userId)
var routineTemp = Routine()
var exercisesAndSets = [String:Int]()
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

        routineTemp.routineName = dictionary["routineName"] as! String
        let enumerator = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "exercises").children

        while let item = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {

            exercisesAndSets[item.key] = item.childSnapshot(forPath: "numberOfSets").value! as? Int
        }

    }

    routineTemp.routineExercisesAndSets = exercisesAndSets

    self.routines.append(routineTemp)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

} , withCancel: nil)
```

If anyone else is having a similar issue, I hope this helps provide an idea of one way to access the values.